# Repeat Test Written with Dalek.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ui-testing

I develop some UI tests (running with Phantom.js configuration)

The tests themselves are very simple, for example (see some sample code below):

- Browse a page - confirm the title expected is correct
- Click a button/item to select an item from a list - confirm that the accurate item has been selected.

  ```
  module.exports = {
     'NodeCeller home page': function (test) {
       test
         .open('http://localhost:3000')
         .assert.title().is('Node Cellar', 'Node Cellar is now open')
         .done();
   },

   'NodeCeller Start Browsing Click': function (test) {
       test
      .click('a[href="#wines"]')
      .assert.url('http://localhost:3000/#wines', 'Showing wines selection')
      .done();
    },

    'NodeCellar Browse First Wine': function (test) {
       test
          .click('#content > div > ul > li > a')
          .assert.text('legend','Wine Details', 'Showing Wines Details')
          .done();
    },
  };
  ```

My question is this, I'd like to run the same set of tests in a loop for several times.
I have googled for Dalek.JS help and samples but I couldn't find any sample or article of how to do that.

Any help would be highly appreciated